# Filter the file read from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the multiple s3 files located inside the bucket folder in the format as below

```
s3://bucket/student_id=1/year=2019/month=06/day=09/file1.csv
s3://bucket/student_id=1/year=2019/month=06/day=07/file2.csv
s3://bucket/student_id=2/year=2019/month=06/day=10/file3.csv
s3://bucket/student_id=3/year=2019/month=06/day=11/file4.csv
```

In python using boto3 can I get the file in the way like:

*s3://bucket/student_id=*/year={arg_year}/month={arg_month}/day={arg_day}/*

where year, month and day are passed through parameters. Also, is there a way to identify which client data is being processed or which client data is finished. Like
Processing for student_id=1
........
Processing for student_id=2
For now only I can do is get all value from s3 which takes huge time.

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket("usergram")
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
```

Comment: It sounds like you want the program that is writing files into the S3 bucket to also generate notifications about its progress. You can do that by creating an SNS topic and an SQS queue that subscribes to it; then your code that writes files can signal the topic as it adds data, and your code that reads from the bucket can listen to the queue to find out when new data is added.

Comment: Consider storing the list of S3 objects in a database which you can then update as files are processed and you can query for files not yet processed. Or, if it makes sense to simply process the files as they appear in S3, then consider triggering a Lambda function when each file is uploaded.

Comment: Actually, instead of writing the files in S3, I want to read all the files in S3 processed it and get a result. The processing might be done on 1 month or 2 months or 2 weeks